# how to use dataframe on all app.route flask?

Tags: python, excel, flask

I want to Create a web using Flask which can download a file from it. I use dataframe and want use this dataframe to all my app route.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   df=pd.read_sql_query(querysql(date), cnx )
   return return render_template("data.html",data=df.to_html())

@app.route('/download')
def download():
   output = 'codes_people.xlsx'
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Codes")
   writer.save()
   return send_file(output, attachment_filename="testing.xlsx", as_attachment=True)
```

The document Excel I get only a blank sheet. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Define dataframe at global scope when initializing your app instance.

```
df=pd.read_sql_query(querysql(date), cnx )

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return return render_template("data.html",data=df.to_html())

@app.route('/download')
def download():
   output = 'codes_people.xlsx'
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Codes")
   writer.save()
   return send_file(output, attachment_filename="testing.xlsx", as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: cant cause the date i get is from form inside function,, i use global but the value i get is still same